# `ulimit -t` entirely unportable between shells and OSs?

Tags: bash, shell, signals, zsh, ulimit

**Update**: This is becoming less of a question and more of a summary. Oh well...

bash, dash, and zsh all come with a builtin command `ulimit`. Each has an option `-t` which accepts a number as an argument, to be understood as CPU time in seconds that processes may consume. Thereafter, they will be sent a signal. So much is clear.

There's a lot that is not clear, though. And I find some of it rather unexpected. In particular, what behaviour you get depends both on the shell and the underlying operating system. I've created a table that summarises the extent of the variability. I'm also including the code for a script that I used to automatically obtain those results. The last test needs root privileges and can be kept from running if you comment out `test_shell_sudo $shell`.

```
|                                              | Darwin/zsh | Darwin/bash | FreeBSD/zsh | FreeBSD/bash | FreeBSD/dash | Linux/zsh  | Linux/bash  | Linux/dash  |
| ulimit -t sets                               | soft limit | both limits | soft limit  | both limits  | both limits  | soft limit | both limits | both limits |
| ulimit -t gets                               | soft limit | soft limit  | soft limit  | soft limit   | soft limit   | soft limit | soft limit  | soft limit  |
| Hard limits can be set below the soft limit  | yes        | no          | yes         | yes          | yes          | yes        | no          | no          |
| Soft limits can be set above the hard limit  | yes        | no          | yes         | no           | no           | yes        | no          | no          |
| Hard limits can be raised without privileges | yes        | no          | yes         | no           | no           | yes        | no          | no          |
| soft signal                                  | SIGXCPU    | SIGXCPU     | SIGXCPU     | SIGXCPU      | SIGXCPU      | SIGXCPU    | SIGXCPU     | SIGXCPU     |
| hard signal                                  | SIGXCPU    | SIGXCPU     | SIGKILL     | SIGKILL      | SIGKILL      | SIGKILL    | SIGKILL     | SIGKILL     |
| Number of SIGXCPUs sent                      | one        | one         | one         | one          | one          | multiple   | multiple    | multiple    |
| Raising soft beyond hard limit raises it     | yes        | impossible* | yes         | no           | no           | yes        | impossible* | impossible* |

* even as root
```

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

get_sigcode() {
    /bin/kill -l |
        tr '\n[a-z]' ' [A-Z]' |
        awk -v name=$1 '
            { for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i) if ($i == name) print i }'
}

create_runner() {
    cat > sig.c <<'EOF'
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int
main()
{
  int runs = 0;
  double x = 0.0;
  for (;;runs++) {
    x += (double)rand() / RAND_MAX;
    if (x >= 1e7) {
      printf("Took %d iterations to reach 1000.\n", runs);
      x = 0.0;
      runs = 0;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
EOF
    cc sig.c -o sig
    rm -f sig.c
    echo Successfully compiled sig.c
}

create_counter() {
    cat > sigcnt.c <<'EOF'
#include <stdatomic.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

sig_atomic_t sig_received;
void handle_signal(int signum) {
  sig_received = signum;
}

int
main()
{
  signal(SIGXCPU, handle_signal);

  int sigxcpu_cnt = 0;
  time_t start, now;
  time(&start);

  int runs = 0;
  double x = 1;
  for (;;) {
    if (sig_received == SIGXCPU) {
      sigxcpu_cnt++;
      sig_received = 0;
    }
    time(&now);
    if (now - start > 5) {
      switch (sigxcpu_cnt) {
      case 0:
        fprintf(stderr, "none\n");
        exit(0);
      case 1:
        fprintf(stderr, "one\n");
        exit(0);
      default:
        fprintf(stderr, "multiple\n");
        exit(0);
      }
    }

    // Do something random that eats CPU (sleeping is not an option)
    x += (double)rand() / RAND_MAX;
    if (x >= 1e7) {
      printf("Took %d iterations to reach 1000.\n", runs);
      x = 0.0;
      runs = 0;
    }
  }
}
EOF
    cc sigcnt.c -o sigcnt
    rm -f sigcnt.c
    echo Successfully compiled sigcnt.c
}

echo_underscored() {
    out1=$1
    out2=''
    for ((i=0; i < ${#out1}; ++i)); do
        out2+='='
    done
    echo $out1
    echo $out2
}


test_shell() {
    shell=$1
    echo_underscored "Testing shell: $shell"

    f() {
        $shell -c 'ulimit -St 3; ulimit -t 2; ulimit -Ht; ulimit -St' | tr -d '\n'
    }
    case `f` in
        22)
            t_sets='both limits';;
        unlimited2)
            t_sets='soft limit';;
        *)
            echo UNEXPECTED;;
    esac
    echo "ulimit -t sets: ${t_sets}"

    f() {
        $shell -c 'ulimit -St 3; ulimit -Ht 4; ulimit -St 3; ulimit -t'
    }
    case `f` in
        3)
            t_gets='soft limit';;
        *)
            echo UNEXPECTED;;
    esac
    echo "ulimit -t gets: ${t_gets}"

    f() {
        $shell -c 'ulimit -St 2; ulimit -Ht 1' >/dev/null 2>&1 &&
            echo yes || echo no
    }
    ht_can_set_below_soft=`f`
    echo "Hard limits can be set below the soft limit: ${ht_can_set_below_soft}"

    f() {
        $shell -c 'ulimit -St 1; ulimit -Ht 2; ulimit -St 3' >/dev/null 2>&1 &&
            echo yes || echo no
    }
    st_can_set_above_hard=`f`
    echo "Soft limits can be set above the hard limit: ${st_can_set_above_hard}"

    f() {
        $shell -c 'ulimit -St 1; ulimit -Ht 2; ulimit -Ht 3' >/dev/null 2>&1 &&
            echo yes || echo no
    }
    hard_can_be_raised=`f`
    echo "Hard limits can be raised without privileges: ${hard_can_be_raised}"

    f() {
        $shell -c 'ulimit -St 1; ./sig' >/dev/null 2>&1
        echo $?
    }
    case $((`f` - 128)) in
        ${sigxcpu})
            soft_signal=SIGXCPU;;
        ${sigkill})
            soft_signal=SIGKILL;;
        *)
            echo UNEXPECTED;
    esac
    echo "soft signal: ${soft_signal}"

    f() {
        $shell -c 'ulimit -St 1; ulimit -Ht 1; ./sig' >/dev/null 2>&1
        echo $?
    }
    case $((`f` - 128)) in
        ${sigxcpu})
            hard_signal=SIGXCPU;;
        ${sigkill})
            hard_signal=SIGKILL;;
        *)
            echo UNEXPECTED;;
    esac
    echo "hard signal: ${hard_signal}"

    f() {
        $shell -c 'ulimit -St 1; ./sigcnt 2>&1 >/dev/null'
    }
    sigxcpus_sent=`f`
    echo "Number of SIGXCPUs sent: ${sigxcpus_sent}"
}

test_shell_sudo() {
    shell=$1
    echo_underscored "Testing shell with sudo: $shell"

    f() {
        sudo $shell -c 'ulimit -St 1; ulimit -Ht 1; ulimit -St 2 && ulimit -Ht' \
            2>/dev/null;
    }
    out=`f`; ret=$?;
    if [[ $ret == 0 ]]; then
        case $out in
            1)
                raising_soft_beyond_hard='no';;
            2)
                raising_soft_beyond_hard='yes';;
            *)
                echo UNEXPECTED;;
        esac
    else
        raising_soft_beyond_hard='impossible'
    fi
    echo "Raising soft beyond hard limit raises it: ${raising_soft_beyond_hard}"
}

main() {
    echo "Testing on platform: $(uname)"

    sigxcpu=$(get_sigcode XCPU)
    sigkill=$(get_sigcode KILL)
    echo Number of signal SIGXCPU: ${sigxcpu}
    echo Number of signal SIGKILL: ${sigkill}

    create_runner
    create_counter
    echo

    for shell in zsh bash dash; do
        which $shell >/dev/null || continue;
        test_shell $shell
        echo
    done

    for shell in zsh bash dash; do
        which $shell >/dev/null || continue;
        test_shell_sudo $shell
        echo
    done
}

main
```

The [corresponding gist](https://gist.github.com/pipping/393f1c5d5fe388a4c7903b53e4e416ff) also comes with a nicer table.

Comment: These limits are meant as a warning to the user.  There are also soft and hard limits set (usually) in the kernel, i.e. they are not managed by a shell.  Again, the soft limit is considered to be a warning that limits may soon be reached, and a program can extend its process's limit to the hard limit, but no further (unless root).  See `man 2 getrlimit` and `man 2 setrlimit` for the underlying C APIs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, here are the absolute rules of ulimits that all processes including shells are restricted to:

- Anyone can lower their own hard limit.
- It requires special privileges to raise a hard limit.
- The soft limit can be raised up and down, as long as it's less than the hard limit.

With this in mind:

> 1. Should I be able to raise the limit set by an earlier call to ulimit again?

Soft limit, yes. Hard limit, no.

> bash appears to think no whereas zsh thinks yes.

Bash defaults to setting the hard limit. Zsh defaults to setting the soft limit.

Zsh documents this, but bash does not. In any case, `strace` tells all:

```
$ strace -e setrlimit zsh -c 'ulimit -t 1'
setrlimit(RLIMIT_CPU, {rlim_cur=1, rlim_max=RLIM64_INFINITY}) = 0

$ strace -e setrlimit bash -c 'ulimit -t 1'
setrlimit(RLIMIT_CPU, {rlim_cur=1, rlim_max=1}) = 0
```

> 2. What signals will I be sent?

If you exceed the soft CPU limit, you [will receive a SIGXCPU](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getrlimit.html). What happens after that is undefined in POSIX. Linux will, according to its man page, re-send SIGXCPU every second until the hard limit is reached, at which point you're SIGKILL'd.

> Do I get a grace period?

You can choose your own grace period by setting the soft limits.

#### Caveat:

On `zsh`, setting the hard limit without also setting the soft limit will cause the limit to apply to children instead of the shell:

```
zsh% ulimit -H -t 1
zsh% ( while true; do true; done )   # is a child, soon killed
zsh% while true; do true; done       # not a child, never dies
```

If you set both limits at once, they apply to the current shell like in `bash`:

```
zsh% ulimit -SH -t 1
zsh% while true; do true; done       # will now die, just like bash
```

I have no idea what the rationale behind this is.

Comment: Yes, I tested and confirmed it all. Can you give a series of commands run as non-root that demonstrates what you're seeing?

Comment: With (a) and (b) you tried with the while loop as demonstrated in this answer and not with your own code, right?

Comment: sorry. my testing must've been flawed. what you said is entirely correct.